# Flag exact duplicate questions without sufficient privileges?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where on earth is the mark as duplicate UI on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118124/where-on-earth-is-the-mark-as-duplicate-ui-on-stack-overflow)

I just came accross [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10235466/1025391). From my point of view, the OP self provided the link to the exact duplicate. As one would expect, he receives pretty similar answers.

I would vote to close in this case. But I appear to not have sufficient privileges to do this. So, what would be the recommended strategy to cope with this? Post in chat? Flag for Moderator attention? Wait until I have 3000 rep?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually flag it for closure with 15+ rep. These options are accessible via the "it doesn't belong here" option. The menu this leads to is the exact same you'd use to vote to close once you get to 3k rep.

This won't actually count as a vote, but it *will* attract people who can vote to close (normal users with [access to the flag queue](/privileges/moderator-tools), and moderators).

Answer (score 2):

Flag->It doesn't belong here->exact duplicate

Comment: Thanks! I didn't knew this flag thing was nested this way.