# How can we edit the "Flag Posts" help page to indicate that users gain the ability to flag to close at 50 rep?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center

The [Flag Posts help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) says the privilege is awarded at 15 rep, which is true. However, there is no indication on that page that the ability to "flag to close" actually requires 50 rep. *(See the answer to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217242/why-dont-i-see-the-option-to-mark-a-question-as-a-duplicate) for the reason why.)* This is confusing for users with more than 15 but less than 50 rep, and I think the help page should be edited to reflect the current UX.

According to [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/introducing-a-brand-new-consolidated-help-center#comment557276_182819), only SE staff can update Help Center pages. How can I get this update request to their attention?

Comment: I changed your post to a feature request.  This is exactly how you get their attention.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Indeed, it seems I didn't read the description of the `feature-request` tag closely enough: *This tag is for proposals of new features on the site, **or requests for a change to an existing feature***. Then again, I also wasn't exactly sure whether the text of the help page is considered a "feature". I think perhaps having the `help-center` tag may also get the attention of the responsible parties? Would you like to create an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting here on meta is the way to get our attention (and using the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag is fine; I guess copy isn't technically a feature, but we don't need to get that picky).

I've updated both the flagging and commenting privileges pages to note that certain types of flags require the ability to post comments.