# Information on who can flag to close in the help center is contradictory

Tags: bug, flags, privileges, help-center, wording

The [help page on the flagging privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) says:

> 4. […]
> 5. Flag to close (questions only)*
>
>    1. Duplicate question*
>    2. Off-topic (with sub-reasons)*
>    3. Unclear what you're asking*
>    4. Too broad*
>    5. Primarily opinion-based*
> 6. […]
>
> * these options will not appear in the flag menu until you have earned [comment threshold] reputation (the amount required for commenting).

The [help page on the commenting privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) says:

> Please note that the comment privilege is also linked to the flagging privilege. In the flag-to-close menu, the options to flag as duplicate or as off-topic will not appear if you do not have sufficient reputation to post a comment because these flag types automatically generate a comment when you submit the flag.

This has the following, related¹ problems:

1. The help on commenting says that only flagging as a dupe and off-topic is restricted, while the help on flagging says that all flagging for closure is restricted. This is contradictory.
2. On sites where the commenting privilege is earned before the flagging privilege (Meta SE and private betas), the following line from the help on flagging makes little sense and may confuse readers:

   > these options will not appear in the flag menu until you have earned [comment threshold] reputation (the amount required for commenting).
3. The help on the commenting privilege states that flagging as off-topic automatically generates a comment. This is not true. Only voting to close as off-topic **with a custom reason** automatically generates a comment and this option is only available to those who acquired the close privilege.

For the purpose of discussion, it may be interesting to know, what alternative for point 1 is actually true. [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217242/255554) suggests that the text on flagging is correct, but this may be outdated.

---

<sup>¹ They probably all originated [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217329/255554).</sup>

Comment: Looks like Help Center was changed meanwhile, is there still an issue?

Comment: Per [Laura's answer to another post back in 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217375/335251), it seems like the relevant wording was updated long ago... (I'm not sure the system even works the same way anymore; neither help center page mentions anything of the sort anymore, as far as I can tell.)